# Move from Grails 3 to Spring-Boot

Tags: spring-boot, grails

Our project uses the Grails stack with Grails 3.1.5, GORM and Groovy. We are trying to move away from Grails and just use Spring-Boot. We have not settled yet if we want to get rid of GORM and Groovy as well.

Our reasons are:

- a lot of trouble in upgrading to Grails 3.2.2
- lack of up-to-date plugins
- bugs in grails and it's plugins
- no community
- bad documentation
- mostly figuring out the magic of Grails takes up more time than writing everything on your own

Does anyone have any experience or suggestions on how to deal with a migration like this?

Thanks :)

Comment: If my answer helped out, I would appreciate you marking it as such.

Comment: @loteq it was not supposed to be a rant or similar. I stated the reasons, to exclude answers like "you already have SpringBoot when you use Grails". I can see that you've taken that very personal and I'm sorry for any offence.
Problem is that "just leaving all grails-y things and replace them with boot-y annotations" doesn't do the trick. That's why I asked about experiences or any other advice.

Comment: I actually think that my suggestion is your best shot. I will not comment further about the rantiness of your comments, but my opinion stands.

Comment: Your reasons might be based on your experience. My experience is good community and documentation. Maybe you need to get involved more closely with the community. Not sure where you tried to reach them. Slack is a good place, also here in stack overflow you get a lot of good answers.

Answer (score 11):

In any case, even though you seem to have written your question in a way that is likely to create more discussion than help you out, here's my 2 cents, FWIW:

You're already in a spring boot application! You can leave all the annoying grails-y and groovy-y things behind and code your app in java, with all the boot-y annotations you want.

This is not to be facetious! It is a good methodology to slowly extract your grails artifacts and replace them, with spring-boot components, without having to break your app.

So here, from a non-existing community member of grails, good luck.

**UPDATE:**
After answering your question, I thought back to all the times a grails developer answered a question for me, every time I spent  hours through the rabbit hole of the grails web sites, reading mind-blowing documentation and tutorials, and I thought I owed it to all these people doing this for FREE, to come back and defend them.

The grails and groovy communities are one of the friendliest I have ever come accross. You should bother to go to a conference or visit their slack community.

Some links to grails' outstanding documentation sites:
http://grails.org/documentation.html

Grails guides:
http://guides.grails.org/

Either you haven't looked or you have to tell me what your standard is.